# OSB transform String to DateTime (xsl or xquery)

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, xquery, osb

I'm working with Oracle OSB and I have the following incoming xml message:

```
<db:InputParameters>
    <db:DETAILS>
        <db:DETAILS_ITEM>
            <db:Mutate>W</db:Mutate>
            <db:Date>2020-04-06T14:43</db:Date>
            <db:Account>T</db:Account>
        </db:DETAILS_ITEM>
        <db:DETAILS_ITEM>
            <db:Mutate>W</db:Mutate>
            <db:Date>2020-04-06T14:43</db:Date>
            <db:Account>T</db:Account>
        </db:DETAILS_ITEM>
    </db:DETAILS>
</db:InputParameters>
```

The element "Date" is a "string" -> according to the xsd. But the application that I'm sending this message to, expects a "DateTime" type. So I need to transform the element "Date" from type "String" to type "DateTime". Keep in mind that the incoming message has more than one element called "Date". I tried a For Each stage with a replace action but I couldn't get it to work.

Also, I tried to concat ":00" to the "Date" element with the expression: `fn:concat($body/*:inputparameters/*:DETAILS/*:DETAILS_ITEM/*:Date,':00')`
This didn't seem to work either.

What would be the most simple solution to this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe giving some insight where are you sending the data to would give someone clue and by their experience they'd hint you how to parse it at the other side with ease. Bringing more context to your question would make it easier to get in your shoes.

Comment: What else do you need to know aside from that the receiving party expects a DateTime type for element "Date"? Unless you have a specific question then I would happily give you some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT you can change the value of the element as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:db="http://example.com/db"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="db:DETAILS_ITEM/db:Date">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ':00')"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsv

Note that this is simply changing the contents of that element to a value which can be parsed as an `xs:dateTime`. There is no schema involved or any validation done. You will need to adapt the namespace declaration `xmlns:db="http://example.com/db"` to the one of the input document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Martin, this worked indeed with some additional changes as you mentioned. I also found a different appraoch to this and I answerd accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a colleague I found the following solution.

In the first pipeline that picks up the incoming message from the queue, I added a "For-each stage" with a "replace stage" inside that looks like this:

```
For Each [ curValue ] in [*:InputParameters/*:DETAILS/*:DETAILS_ITEM/*:Date]
of [ body ]
Indexed by [ curIndex ] with total count in [ curCount ]
Do (

Replace [ node contents ] of [ *:InputParameters/*:DETAILS/*:DETAILS_ITEM[$curIndex]/*:Date]
in [ body ] with [ fn:concat($curValue,":00")]
```